# How to get the Page Type in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get the current type page by echoing its type .I have tried several methods but none has worked.
[image]

Screenshot from the Backend
Simply I want to check the Agencement value 
Sorry for not providing essays as none has worked

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what you need please explain me

Comment: I deleted my post as your question is not common, you used some extension so please provide me your field name then we can help you.

Comment: I need to get the value Widgetized Page for the current page

Comment: ok bro so can you share me admin  details,

Comment: because it seems you added an extension for it.

Comment: In fresh Magento, it is no default column. right?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
$pageIdentifier = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
Mage::log($pageIdentifier,null,'pageType.log');
```

[MAGENTO ROOT]/var/log/pageType.log

Answer (score 0):

do you try in block file?

```
$this->getRequest()->getFullActionName()
```